# Google drive api :cannot create table from files.list?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

**UPDATE**, **SOLVED!**

*I can get it works now by using this code,might be useful for some people*

```js
function listFiles() {
  gapi.client.drive.files.list({
    'pageSize': 10,
    'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name,webViewLink,mimeType,description)"

  }).then(function(response) {
    //appendPre('Files:');
    var files = response.result.files;
    if (files && files.length > 0) {
    
      document.write("<table border=1>");
      document.write("<th>Name</th>");
      document.write("<th>ID</th>");
      document.write("<th>URL</th>");
      document.write("<th>TYPE</th>");
      document.write("<th>Description</th>");
      
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      
        var file = files[i];
        
        var fileName = file.name;
        var id = file.id;
        var url = file.webViewLink;
        var type = file.mimeType;
        var des = file.description;

        // create row and cell

        document.write("<tr>");
        document.write("<td width=100>" + fileName + "</td>");
        document.write("<td width=100>" + id + "</td>");
        document.write("<td width=100><a href=" + url + ">URL</a></td>");
        document.write("<td width=100>" + type + "</td>");
        document.write("<td width=100>" + des + "</td>");
        document.write("</tr>");

      }
      document.write("</table>");
    }
  })
}
```

**__________________________________________________________________________**

I'm trying to list files by using Google Drive api and create table from a list. I can get a list of files but I'm stuck with how to append data to table.

So far I tried this code (tried create table with filename only but actually I want to apply every data)

```js
function listFiles() {
  gapi.client.drive.files.list({
    'pageSize': 10,
    'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name,webViewLink,mimeType,description)"

  }).then(function(response) {
    var files = response.result.files;
    if (files && files.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        var fileName = [];
        var fileName = file.name;
        var id = file.id;
        var url = file.webViewLink;
        var type = file.mimeType;
        var des = file.description;

        var numrow = fileName.length;

        console.log(fileName);
        createTable(fileName, id, url, type, des, numrow);
      }
    } else {
      appendPre('No files found.');
    }
  });
}

function createTable(fileName, id, url, type, des, numrow) {

  var table = document.createElement("table");
  for (var i = 0; i < fileName.length; i++) {
    var row = table.insertRow();
    for (var j = 0; j < fileName[i].length; j++) {
      var cell = row.insertCell();
      cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fileName[i][j]));
    }
  }
  return table;
}
```

but nothing show with no error.
So I don't know what did I do wrong about this?
If anyone know please help,thanks.